# how to get the user@machine prompt on zsh

Tags: zsh

I recently installed zsh and defaulted to it over bash. However one thing I noticed was that the "user@machine~" prompt which appears before every command was missing. Any pro tips on how to fix this would be awesome. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty bare by default. I'd recommend to use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) instead. You can use [my zshrc](https://gist.github.com/Hi-Angel/6f4bc6b0aec6020e179d81a878ea7f70), and to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `user@machine~` prompt is missing in zsh by default. But you can still have it by installing a theme. [Find a zsh theme here.](https://zshthem.es/all/) One example of a theme that has `user@machine~` is **`alanpeabody`**.